# What is the best way to use MicrosoftReportView control in ASP.NET MVC framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reportviewer

Exactly same as the title of my question,

What is the best way to use MicrosoftReportView control in ASP.NET MVC framework?

I need to use report viewer control in asp.net mvc application, but I am so confused that how to use that control in mvc framework without violation of mvc pattern.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can mix both WebForms and MVC pages in the same application, so you may want to just develop a single WebForms page for the one that requires the ReportView.  Hanselman [describes a similar scenario](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PlugInHybridsASPNETWebFormsAndASPMVCAndASPNETDynamicDataSideBySide.aspx) on his blog.  If you need it in an MVC page, you may want to look the following for hints on how to do so.  I have no idea if this particular control will work or not, since I haven't tried this.

http://codebetter.com/blogs/david.hayden/archive/2007/12/27/asp-net-mvc-and-accessing-server-controls-in-codebehind.aspx

http://flux88.com/blog/leveraging-existing-asp-net-features-in-asp-net-mvc/